# Sunspot scoped queries not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm implementing a fulltext search using [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) with scoped queries, but it's not working. When I remove the 'with' queries and search, it works, but when I add the queries in it does not. I've looked at the documentation and it should be structured correctly, any thoughts?

Name and category are both strings in the Items table. As a bare bones attempt, I've been    trying to get only the 'electronics' items with an empty search that normally results in all items being displayed w/o the query.

Model

```
searchable do
  text :name, :category
  string :category
end
```

Controller

```
def search
  @search = Item.search do
    fulltext (params[:search])
    with(:category, 'electronics')
  end

  @items = @search.results

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: have you `reindex`ed your model and committed to Sunspot? What if you search without text but with `with`?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined field :category to be both text and a string. 
It appears from your controller code that you want to use it as a string.
Does the problem go away after amending your :category declaration?

By the way, what's name doing here - surely name must be a string. Do you have a text field in your model? text here means a large blob of text, with possibly hundreds of characters, if not thousands.

Comment: I originally defined :category as a string but I got an error, when I set it as text I did not. Setting as both was a suggestion I received and I didn't get an error, but filtering still wasn't working. And yeah name is a string, but for some reason I can't do fulltext search with strings, works when its text though. I decided to change category to integer and it works when I search by number, though I don't believe that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue where my `with` filters were causing no results.

Restarting Rails/Solr and then running `rake sunspot:reindex` fixed it for me.

I tried running `rake sunspot:reindex` several times (with frustration), but it didn't work until I restarted Solr and then reindexed.

I'm guessing it's because I'm starting Sunspot via a Foreman `Procfile`, and the Rails instance tied to Solr does not reload model classes when you change them. (Similar to how it treats `worker` processes... you have to restart Rails to get Foreman to pick up the changes to job code.)